# force reload screen on an event of a child component

Tags: react-native

it is sort of too late to change things so I was wondering if there is a way to do it in my functional components. Basically, I have a main screen with a child component in it:

ScreenHome.js

```
      <ChildComponent/>
```

ChildComponent does something and upon completion of the process, I want to reload the screen. ChildComponent is in all the screens so I need it to to reload the current screen. I have seen:

```
     this.forceUpdate()
```

but I am using functional components only so that can't apply. How would I go reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a state in your parent (screen) and pass the setter to your child.
E.g.

```
const [getForceUpdate, setForceUpdate] = useState(false);

<Parent>
   <Child forceAnUpdate={() => setForceUpdate(!getForceUpdate)}/>
</Parent>
```

Call props.forceAnUpdate when your child process is done.
This will trigger a re-render in all your components.